# Can I download Office 2010 to my laptop now, then my desktop when I buy one?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010

I am ready to purchase MS Office to download. I understand (from other FAQs) that I can install Office on one desktop and one portable device. But most people will be using their desktop as their primary machine, whereas my primary machine will be my laptop.

Should I download it to my laptop, or an external hard-drive? And how do I install it when I buy a desktop?

I'm really stuck on the logistics for this one!

Thanks.

Comment: That type of licenses are limited to x number of computers, it doesn't matter the type (e.g. it wouldn't check if you install it in two desktops). See John T answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Office 2010 Home and Business as well as Office 2010 Professional are limited to 2 PCs. Office 2010 Home and Student is limited to **3** I believe. If you have one of the 2 prior versions, there shouldn't be any restrictions to installing it. I'd download it to the external so you don't have to worry about transferring it again once you get the new machine.

The FPP editions (Fully Packaged Product) are the ones I am referring to above. If you purchased a Product Key Card (PKC) like this:

[image]

then you are limited to 1 installation.

The install should be straightforward like any other application. Run the executable and enter your licensing info when prompted. If you are having any difficulties with the product keys, a quick call to Microsoft usually straightens things out.

Comment: Thanks John, and Alberto. Sounds like it should be ok to get it on to my laptop, then on to a desktop in the future.